# How can I use a comparison function with more than 2 arguments with c++ vector?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have an integer `k` and vector `A`, and need to sort so that `abs(A[i] - k) < abs(A[i + 1] - k)`

```
    int n ;
    int X;
    cin >> n >> X;
    vector<int> a(n);
    FORi(i,0,n - 1) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    stable_sort(a.begin(),a.end(), [](int a,int b){
        return abs(a - X) < abs(b - X);
    });
```

This does not work.

Comment: Put X into square brackets of your lambda

Comment: Please show a [mre], this should include the complete program and any messages you get compiling and/or running it.